# Full text search query generating error, why?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, full-text-search

Why do I get a MySQL error from this query?

```
SELECT *, MATCH($SW) AGAINST(reb, keb, gloss) as Score 
FROM dictionary 
WHERE MATCH($SW) AGAINST(reb, keb, gloss) 
ORDER BY Score DESC;
```

I'm trying to test Full Text search but I can't create a working query it seems like.

Comment: Well it's just a regular MySQL error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''eat') AGAINST(reb) as Score FROM dictionary WHERE MATCH('eat') AGAINST(reb) ORD' at line 1"

Comment: the above query did not generate that error

Comment: Could this be because I'm running an old MySQL? I'm using server version 5.5.32.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you gave the error message, but I think I can guess the fix. You forgot to quote the strings:

```
SELECT *, MATCH('$SW') AGAINST(reb, keb, gloss) as Score 
FROM dictionary 
WHERE MATCH('$SW') AGAINST(reb, keb, gloss) 
ORDER BY Score DESC;
```